# Firebase Session Management with Tokens or Cookies?

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-authentication

I am asking myself if its possible to manage different/multiply sessions of an user only with firebase 3. Currently my application is build like this: The Main user can create a main company (for example Google). Inside Google he can also create an another company like Appurify, YouTube etc.

What I want is that the user has the possibility to switch between the companies. So if he logs in with the YouTube account he will see the dashboard with all data of YouTube. He should easy switch to a other company, for example to Appurify and the data would be loaded from Appurify.

Normally, I did it with cookies before. I wrote a cookie and put the companyId into the cookie. With this feature I can read on each device from the cookie. I want also that the user can login on different devices an can view on an iPad the data of Appurify and maybe on the Desktop the data of YoutTube.

How can I handle this in firebase 3? Or should I do it with cookies?

What I already tried was this:

Database Model:

[See image here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/10Nl7.jpg)

And in the code

```
var auth = app.auth()
var currentUser = auth.currentUser

auth.currentUser.getToken(false).then(function(tokenId) {
  // and there I am querying by tokenId.
  // like
  database.ref('userSessions')
     .child(currentUser.uid)
     .equalTo(tokeId)
     .orderByChild('token')
     .on('value', function(){ // here i get the company id and log the compnay. If no token exists I create a new one. })
}
```

Comment: So you want the tokens to be stored in a database only? Or are you looking for some 'in-built' solution?

Comment: @DeividasKaržinauskas: If there is a way to store only it db it will be cool, but I am open for other solutions too. My goal is, that a user can login with the same account on different devices on the same time and can view different company on each device their data.